# How can I center a small CCTMXTileMap in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making a tile-based 2d RPG with cocos2d. I am using CCTMXTileMaps for my maps. My player is centered on the the screen and the map moves around it (except when the player walks towards the edge of the map, where they walk away from center and actually move). This system works well in large maps. In small maps however, the map is anchored to the top right of the screen. While the mechanics still work, it would be nice to have those small maps automatically centered.

**How can I make maps that are smaller than the screen's dimensions be centered?** I want the map to be centered in the "red box". (The red box is just here for illustrative purposes, it's not actually there in code.)

[image]

**EDIT:**

So I figured out how to do it in theory, but I'm having trouble understanding the coordinate system.  I'm using the following code to center the map but it's not behaving as expected. The map loads off of the screen.

```
    if ((self.tileMap.contentSize.height < screenSize.height) && (self.tileMap.contentSize.width < screenSize.width)) {

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    CGPoint centerOfView = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);        


    CGPoint centerOfMap = CGPointMake((self.tileMap.mapSize.width*self.tileMap.tileSize.width)/2, (self.tileMap.mapSize.height*self.tileMap.tileSize.height)/2);

    self.tileMap.anchorPoint = centerOfMap;
    self.tileMap.position = centerOfView;

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: define "breaking something", does it crash or not behave as you'd like?

Comment: @FraserGraham Edited. It runs, but does not behave as I'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is quite simple, although I was missing a few things. The most basic code for centering the map in the parent is this:

```
    //
    //  Get the center of the 
    //  screen/map layer (which are the same)
    //

    CGPoint centerOfSelf = CGPointMake(self.contentSizeInPixels.width/2, self.contentSizeInPixels.height/2);

    //
    //  Position the map in the center
    //

    tileMap.position = CGPointMake(centerOfSelf.x - (tileMap.contentSizeInPixels.width/2), centerOfSelf.y - (tileMap.contentSizeInPixels.height/2));
```

The above mentioned code will work if you load one map per scene. However, if you have (like I do) one "world" scene that loads the maps and related data, then you need to do things a little differently. You see, loading a map which is larger than the screen will cause the layer to "stretch" and resize itself to fit the larger map. In doing so, the above code will center and subsequently loaded maps in the "stretched" map scene. So, to counteract this, I first have to resize the "world scene" layer to match the size of the screen. To do so, I use the following code:

```
//
//  Reset the size of the bounding
//  area so that we can properly 
//  center maps that are smaller than
//  the bounding area of the screen.
//

CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
self.contentSizeInPixels = screenSize; 

//move camera
self.position = CGPointZero;
```

Note that I also move the "camera" back to the 0,0 position, in case we've moved away in following our main character.